# Exclude subfolders from geoip redirect

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, geoip

I am using this geoip redirect extension for magento. 
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Sandfox_GeoIP

It works well and I use a file called geoipredirect.php to redirect to store views/websites (called via index.php):

```
<?php
Mage::app();
$geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
$country = $geoIP->getCountry();

if (strcmp($country,'DE') == 0) {
    $mageRunType = 'website';
    $mageRunCode = 'website_de';
}

elseif(strcmp($country,'AT') == 0) {
    $mageRunType = 'website';
    $mageRunCode = 'website_at';
}

else
{
    $mageRunType = 'website';
    $mageRunCode = 'base';
}
Mage::reset();
```

Now I need some some links containing subfolders NOT to be redirected. I have added below code. But the listed URL that includes the subfolder still gets redirected. Any idea whats wrong with the code?

```
<?php
Mage::app();
$geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
$country = $geoIP->getCountry();

if( ! is_super_admin() && current_page_url() != 'https://domain.com/subfolder/' ){
        if ($country == "CH" ) {
        redirect("https://domain.com/subfolder/");
        exit;
 }


elseif (strcmp($country,'DE') == 0) {
    $mageRunType = 'website';
    $mageRunCode = 'website_de';
}

elseif(strcmp($country,'AT') == 0) {
    $mageRunType = 'website';
    $mageRunCode = 'website_at';
}


else
{
    $mageRunType = 'website';
    $mageRunCode = 'base';
}
Mage::reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this finally by using Amastys GeoIp extension.

Comment: Hi, Is that extension supports varnish cache enabled site?